# Unity How To Keep Item Data When The Player Drops The Item

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void Equip(Transform equipment) {
        if (currentEquipment == null) {
            if (equipment.GetComponent<IEquipabble>() != null) {
                currentEquipment = Instantiate(equipment, equipSlot);
                
            }
            else {
                Debug.LogError("Equipment Invalid");
            }
        }
    }

    private void DropItem() {
        if (currentEquipment != null) {
            Item droppedItem = currentEquipment.GetComponent<IEquipabble>().GetItem();

            Instantiate(droppedItem, dropPosition.position,Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(currentEquipment.gameObject);
            
            currentEquipment = null;
        }
    }

    private void TakeItem() {
        float grabRadius = 3f;
        RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.CircleCast(transform.position, grabRadius, Vector2.zero,0,equippableLayer);
        if (hitInfo.collider != null) {
            print(hitInfo.collider.name);
            
            if (hitInfo.collider.TryGetComponent<Item>(out Item item)) {
                Equip(item.ItemSO.equipmentPrefab);
                Destroy(item.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
```

So basically i have two prefabs one for equipping and one for picking up from the ground, i have a gun object that has currentAmmo variable, so player shoots and then currentAmmo decreases let's say current ammo is 3 now, but when player drops the equipped GameObject, we delete the gameObject, the problem starts here because if the player tries to get the same dropped object from ground the currentAmmo variable sets itself to maximum. I need to pass the data to droppedObject but i could'not find a solution. i tried several things for passing data but in the end i was instantiating a new object so i cant pass any data.

when dropping item i created a temp GameObject for holding the data  then i passed the data to Item class which handles the taking the item from the ground but data doesnt pass, i think the problem is with instantiating because when you instatiate an object it creates new object not the previous one even if you set it.

Answer (score 0):

Before you Destroy(currentEquipment.gameObject); could you grab the component you need? Then create a new method for IEquipabble like LoadItemData() and pass the component in?

Comment: i can do that but IEquippable interface has guns flashlight and other items, how can i check the current equipment type

Comment: From my experience, we usually don't destroy items if switching, rather disable them. And then when you pick up an item you can enable and transfer stats. 

To answer your question you can check if a object implements a interface by using the "is" keyword. 

Check this article: learn.unity.com/tutorial/interfaces#63560ef5edbc2a0bfffa7029 Else I would follow a tutorial like this: youtube.com/watch?v=8kKLUsn7tcg

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a way, im not sure if it's a proper way but it works :D

```
private void Equip(Transform equipment) {
    if (currentEquipment == null) {
        if (equipment.GetComponent<IEquipabble>() != null) {
            if (equipment.GetComponent<IEquipabble>().GetItem().isDroppedBefore) {
                currentEquipment = equipment;
                equipment.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }else {
                currentEquipment = Instantiate(equipment, equipSlot);
                currentEquipment.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }
            
            
        }
        else {
            Debug.LogError("Equipment Invalid");
        }
    }
}

private void DropItem() {
    if (currentEquipment != null) {
        Item droppedItem = currentEquipment.GetComponent<IEquipabble>().GetItem();
        droppedItem.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        droppedItem.transform.position = dropPosition.position;
        droppedItem.isDroppedBefore = true;
        droppedItem.itemPrefab = currentEquipment;
        currentEquipment.SetParent(droppedItem.itemPrefab);
        droppedItem.itemPrefab.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        currentEquipment = null;
        
        
    }
}

private void TakeItem() {
    float grabRadius = 3f;
    RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.CircleCast(transform.position, grabRadius, Vector2.zero,0,equippableLayer);
    if (hitInfo.collider != null) {
        print(hitInfo.collider.name);
        
        if (hitInfo.collider.TryGetComponent<Item>(out Item item)) {
            Equip(item.itemPrefab);
            item.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
    
}
```

i was getting the equippable objects from a scriptable object that item class holds, because how scriptable object works i can not set the SO prefab from outside, so i changed it and make it a variable for item class and then activating and deactivating the objects worked, thanks for the help btw Jflyer45